# How to clone a python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm using python 3.9.0 (and tested 3.9.2) on Windows 10. I'm attempting to clone a virtual environment to another Windows 10 machine. I learned the hard way that copy/paste isn't a good solution, and I discovered virtualenv-clone.

The command looks like this:

```
virtualenv-clone myVenv myVenv_clone
```

The error I get is:

```
File "c:\users\freddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\clonevirtualenv.py", line 55, in _virtualenv_sys
    p = subprocess.Popen([executable,
  File "c:\users\freddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\freddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I've read several different reasons for this error. Some even talk about the python version being an issue, but I'm lost on where to go next.

***UPDATE***
Based on the comments, I tested python 3.8.9 and ended up with the same error. I took a closer look and virtualenv-clone was last updated just after python 3.8.2 was released. I tested 3.8.2, and now I have a new error.

```
Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
```

This error also occurs with 3.8.1, 3.8.0, 3.7.9, and 3.7.6. It seems Python cannot access what it needs to generate random numbers. A few postings suggest something about Python not knowing the %systemroot% environmental variable, but I don't understand how to fix this.

To simplify my testing I'm using a VM and taking snapshots. So, there is only one version of Python install on Win10. Once I run my test and it fails, I restore the OS to its state just before python was installed and then I try another python version.

Comment: Looking at some of the [commits](https://github.com/edwardgeorge/virtualenv-clone), at the moment `virtualenv-clone` seems to recently support up to 3.8. While the `python_requires` does not exclude 3.9, it's not listed in the PyPI classifier list yet.

Comment: Note that the CI does not even include py39. Could you downgrade to py38 temporarily or create an environment to use `virtualenv-clone`?

Comment: The version definitely has an effect. Once I backed up to python 3.8.2 and prior versions, the error went away, but now there is a new one. I've updated the post.

Comment: FWIW, there's an active issue and PR to address 3.9 support: https://github.com/edwardgeorge/virtualenv-clone/issues/64