# Error when cloning a python virtual environment (virtualenv-clone) - Failed to get random numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I recently asked a related question and my first issue was related to virtualenv-clone's support (or lack thereof) for python 3.9.

[How to clone a python virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132478/how-to-clone-a-python-virtual-environment)

I'm now using python 3.8.2 and running the following command:

```
virtualenv-clone myVenv myVenv_clone
```

And I'm receiving this error:

```
Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
```

I added some of this information to the previous post, but it is technically a new question.

This error also occurs with 3.8.1, 3.8.0, 3.7.9, and 3.7.6. It seems Python cannot access what it needs to generate random numbers. A few postings suggest something about Python not knowing the %systemroot% environmental variable and the need to "overwrite variables to the OS environment in subprocess calls." However, I don't understand how to fix this.

To simplify my testing I'm using a VM and taking snapshots. So, there is only one version of Python installed on Win10. Once I run my test and it fails, I restore the OS to its state just before python was installed and then I try another python version.

Comment: You can use pip freeze > requirements.txt and then create a new venv after that just install requrements.txt with -r parameter.

Comment: Do you really need `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment? Can't you use python's inbuilt attribute?

Comment: This is for a situation with an air gapped server. There is no Internet connection. I need to move the setup from another computer with Internet access. I guess this would work if the libraries would reinstall from some kind of cached copy. Any thoughts?